# convert maven script to SBT for Avro source generation

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, avro

I am reading a tutorial published here

https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.6/gettingstartedjava.html

this tutorial has a maven build file which generate java sources for avro schema files.

I wonder if I was writing my project in scala, how would I generate the same source?

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
  <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.6</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>schema</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.6</source>
    <target>1.6</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

How will this piece be converted to SBT? also can the avro tools plugin generate scala sources for the avsc files?

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution? I have the same use case too - I'm looking for an sbt plguin that would automatically generate java source files from the avro schemas at compile time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since avro's maven plugin is target to maven, you should probably look an equivalent plugin to sbt. I don't think they have an official plugin for sbt, but I found these two maintened alternatives in google:

https://github.com/julianpeeters/sbt-avrohugger

https://github.com/andreionut/sbt-avro

Looking at the README's it doesn't seem too far from what you would do in maven/java.